# Remote rescue USB with no keyboard & mouse

Tags: server, ssh, rescue-mode

I have a friend in a different city who has an Ubuntu box that won't boot - it powers on, but that's as far as it gets. They don't have a monitor or keyboard and I'm too far away to easily just drop by and sort it out.

Is there a way I can create a bootable USB image that I can SSH into so that I can attempt a console-based rescue?

This is a bit ... of a stretch but I was thinking:

- Ubuntu rescue CD ISO
- Update to start SSH
- Public key auth with my pubkey preinstalled

I can get him to open a port forward, but ... the other bit is a bit tricky.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: ...and how can that bootable USB help your friend in another city?

Comment: If they don't have a monitor or keyboard, how do you know the Ubuntu box does not boot? How old is this box? Does it have legacy BIOS or modern UEFI?

Comment: Ask your friend to courier (or mail or sneakernet) the system to you; attach screen & keyboard; fix; courier it back.